# Money format when printing number

Tags: ruby, decimal, string-formatting

```
def percent_of
  puts "What is the number?"
  number = gets.chomp.to_f
  puts "What is the percent?"
  percent = gets.chomp.to_f
  total_percent_of = number * percent.to_f
  puts " #{percent}% of #{number} is #{total_percent_of.to_i}."
end
```

Ok so this is a very simple percent of program and works fine. But one thing I don't like is that whenever the console prints out the total it looks like the following example: 75.0% of 417 is 31275.
Now is there any way I could get the total to type out in decimal/money form? Like it should be 312.75 or something like that. Please try and keep your answers simple, I'm new to Ruby. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to fix your math. 75% is equal to 75/100 so you want

```
total_percent_of = number * percent / 100.0
```

Next you need a format string to ensure that `total_percent_of` is always printed with the correct number of decimals:

```
sprintf " #{percent}%% of #{number} is %.2f", total_percent_of
```

(you need the `%%` after `percent` because percent signs have special meaning to sprintf). See [the documentation](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Kernel.html#method-i-sprintf) for more information about string formatting.

Comment: If you're going to use a format string, then use it for all variables. Don't mix them up, because that becomes more difficult to read/maintain: `sprintf " %d%% of %d is %.2f", [percent, number, total_percent_of]`

Comment: I actually prefer `puts "#{percent}% of #{number} is #{'%.2f' % total_percent_of}"` since that localizes the string formatting to the only place that needs it.